# Cross validation while preserving a column (not the target ) distribution

Tags: cross-validation

So i'm doing *cross validation* and then i'm predicting using all the data on a test set ( a hold-out set ). My hold-out set has the **same ratio** on a column than the train ( seems thats how the test set was generated, a function that sampled it and tried to preserve the ratio for the **target** classes, and a **particular column** ) . My local CV is a bit lower than my score on the test set, and i think the problem is stemming from the fact that i'm using stratification only for 'y'.

Can lack of stratification of that feature be the reason of Cv & test scores aren't really close?

And if so how can i perform stratification for the target and a feature! 
Thanks

Edit : i'm already doing stratification on the target since my data is imbalanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to combine the two columns (one predictor and the target) and then stratify using the combined column.

Example: say for some observations, the target and the column take the following values: `target = [0,1,0]` and `column = [A,A,B]`. Then the combined column could look something like `[A0,A1,B0]` and could be used for stratification.

*I'm obviously assuming that the predictor column is categorical - you might have to take a different approach for a continuous variable.*

Comment: It is categorical but i'm not sure to understand the intuition behind this approach

Comment: My thinking is that you want to preserve the _combination_ of values of `target` and `column` in your train and test set... if 25% of data is `(target == 0)&(column=='A')` then 25% of the combined column will be `A0` and so the stratification will preserve the combination. Also, this conversation may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516424/sklearn-train-test-split-on-pandas-stratify-by-multiple-columns